# html radio button has to be selected by default on page load

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I am trying to do make the radio button selected by default on page load.

From the below screen it is a frame which is loaded. I am trying to make the radio buttons enable by using

`document.formName.radioButtonId[1].checked = true;`

Where formName is my form name that I declared in html, radioButtonId is id for radio button I used in html.

```
<div>
 <form name = "formName">
.
.
.
.
   <div>
     <input type = "radio"
            id = "radioButton"
.
.
.
   </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

So my expectation is from the above code Joe radio button has to be enabled.

But the html is not completely loaded and when I do 
`document.formName.radioButtonId[1].checked = true;` the `error on console says radioButton` was undefined because of the form is not available.

I am not able to access any of the elements from `form` until it is completely loaded. Is there any way that I can check for the page title is loaded or visible then do the condition that I want to do?

I tried

```
if (document.readyState === "complete") { //do something }
```

This didn't work because document.readyState is always `complete` as the document is referring to parent document from the screenshot you can see it was referring to background page.

Once the Modify Name is completely loaded then I was able to access formName form and I was able to make `Joe` as selected using `document.formName.radioButtonId[1].checked = true;`

I am making Joe as checked based on condition from the code that I have (fyi). That might change so want to be generic.

[![Modify Name is child to background image like a popup][2]][2]
Need help on how to make Joe as checked after loading the page automatically.

Comment: I don't know how you'd do this in javascript but you really should just add the value "checked" to whichever radio button you want in your html. It's more accessible that way anyways.

Comment: Is it by checked= true or false?

Answer (score 1):

Just put checked inline HTML :

e.g:

```
<input type = "radio" id = "radioButton" value="Joe" checked>Joe
```

Answer (score 1):

You would write in your html `<input type="radio" id="radioButton" checked />`. That's much less complicated than using javascript to do it.

Comment: I tried this but this will always be checked. I want to keep it as a boolean way. The value has to be checked if the value is true & uncheck if it is false

Comment: what do you mean? @uidev913u93419417

Comment: I don't know what you mean, HTML doesn't work like that. You must have some code in javascript that is conflicting with the radio buttons because that's not their normal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type = "radio" id = "radioButton" checked>
```

OR in Javascript

```
window.onload = function() {..}
```

Comment: Tried window.onload that is not helping as the outerframe is already loaded.